# Hiding the Null Fields

Tags: asp.net

I have a data repeater that is reading a few different fields. However, some information being pulled is empty. I would like to hide these fields in this case.

I am not sure how best to go about this. I have tried the following methods:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:db %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT GrName, GrRoom
                                FROM [Group] WHERE GrName LIKE 'A%' ORDER BY GrName  && * IS NOT NULL">
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <!-- output to page -->
            <div data-role="collapsible-set">
                <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
            <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
                                <p>Room: <%# Eval("GrRoom")%></p>
                        </div>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Or, do I do something like this in the head?

```
    <script type="text/vbscript">
If (GrRoom = NULL) Then
  display: none;
End If
</script>
```

I'm not sure I'm grasping this concept right now. Basically, I want the following to function to run as:

"If GrRoom is empty, do not display"

Any thoughts on this? I appreciate your insight. I'm relatively new to ASP and .NET, so I'm still learning a lot.

Thank you for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" 
    Visible='<%#  Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(If(TypeOf Eval("GrRoom") Is DbNull, [String].Empty, DirectCast(Eval("GrRoom"), String))) %>'>
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
            <p>
                Room:
                <%# Eval("GrRoom")%></p>
        </div>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

**Edit**

I didn't test it at first, now I've properly tested this code. I'm also checking now and for empty strings. Please try it.

**Edit 2**

I was using C# syntax, sorry, now is edited with VB

**Edit 3**

I added and the DbNull check

Comment: thanks for your help. I was kinda looking at this but can't get it to work either. Always get an error that Identifier is expected.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I get the following error: Leading '.' or '!' can only appear inside a 'With' statement.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for all your updates and explanation. Perhaps getting close? The error got smaller at least, lol. I receive this error: The server tag is not well formed.  It looks okay to me though? I don't see any error with the server tag...

Comment: This is great, thank you so much Adrian for your time and help. This is working well, and it's doing the same function as TheEvilGreebo was sharing too, just a different method. However, let's say I added more field entries to the SELECT group (ex:GrEmail). Is there a way I can still remove the empty GrRoom without removing the GrEmail entry that does have content? In other words, within a group of repeated data, can this code be transformed to individualize removal of fields rather than removing an entire group? Not sure if this makes sense? I tried to clarify this in another post within here

Comment: So let's say I have a building that has a GrRoom, GrEmail, GrPhone. If their is no GrRoom, I just want to remove that field. I don't want to remove the rest of the information for that building like GrEmail and GrPhone because that has content.

Comment: Everything what is in that PlaceHolder won't be rendered as html if there is no info GrRoom. So put in that placeholder the info you don't need to show when there is no GrRoom.

Comment: So it's just a matter of moving the PlaceHolder tag around a bit?

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is not to retrieve the data at all where the field is null, your SQL syntax is close but needs a tweak:

```
SELECT GrName, GrRoom
FROM [Group] 
WHERE GrName LIKE 'A%' 
AND IsNull(GrRoom, '') <> ''
ORDER BY GrName
```

"* is not null" is not valid - IS NOT NULL must refer to a single value, and * refers to all columns in the collected tables utilized in the result set.

&& is also not a valid WHERE construct - you must use "AND" and "OR" not && and ||

Your WHERE conditionals all have to occur *before* the ORDER BY clause

And finally - Like 'A%' will automatically filter out null values because a null cannot be like something with a value.

So if you use the sql as I've written it, that will ensure that GrName is always populated, and so on your ASP side, logic to show/hide controls isn't necessary.

Of course there are reasons to show/hide controls as well - but if you can eliminate unwanted rows from the data being sent to the server, that's less traffic overall, and "as little as necessary and possible" is always a goal when it comes to data transmission.

Comment: Thanks for your help @TheEvilGreebo. Your explanation makes sense, and I appreciate your time in response. I used the 'A%' to get all values that start with the letter A. While I understand your steps, I don't understand why I get an error the moment I switch the WHERE to be before ORDER BY? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you mean in your SQL in the example above, it's because you left part of the where clause AFTER the order by.  You wrote "ORDER BY GrName  && * IS NOT NULL" - but the && * IS NOT NULL is part of filtering, not sorting

Comment: Yep, I did catch that misorder, tweaked something else and got it to show up okay. However, it still didn't rid the empty field. Still trying to troubleshoot this at the moment

Comment: maybe i missed it - is it GrRoom you want to be testing for not empty?  If so, then add "AND IsNull(GrRoom, '') <> ''" to your where clause.  See revised code in my example.  I use the IsNull because NULL <> '' is always false but IsNull(GrRoom,'') <> '' will convert null to '' before the test occurs.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That is the idea. This works great, except perhaps I misinformed my idea. This does get rid of the fields that have an empty GrRoom; however, can it leave other information as well. I don't have it in the above example, but Each room also has an email and telephone. If a room number isn't present, I want it to be gone, but I still want it's info of email and telephone. Basically, I have a directory of buildings I am working with.

Comment: Ok NOW you need to do presentation side checking,a nd Adrian's got what you need there.

Comment: What do you mean by presentation side checking? Is Adrian's code the only two lines I need now?

Comment: I just got this error (wow, they just get more complicated to understand for someone who can barely follow all this as a newbie lol): System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'title'.

Comment: sorry again, instead of title use GrRoom

Comment: Or if I place GrRoom instead of "title", I get: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Maybe the comments about Adrian's answer could go under Adrian's answer.  My inbox is chattering. :)